# Fatal Error after creating Custom Display Suite layout

Tags: display-suite

I am using Display Suite and I created a custom layout called ds_6row when I Flush Cache I get the following error

```
Call to undefined function ds_ds_6row() in /Users/myname/Sites/sitename/sites/all/modules/contrib/ds/includes/ds.registry.inc on line 570
```

I followed the method to create the layout [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1098068)

My structure looks like this:

```
mytheme
--ds_layouts
---ds_6row
----ds_6row.css
----ds_6row.inc
----ds_6row.png
----ds-6row.tpl.php
```

The code for ds_6row.inc is:

```
<?php
function ds_6row() {
  return array(
    'label' => t('6 Row Layout'),
    'regions' => array(
    'info_data' => t('Info_data')
  ),
// Add this line if there is a default css file.
'css' => TRUE,
// Add this line if you're using DS 2.x for icon preview
'image' => TRUE,
);
}
```

The code for ds-6row.tpl.php is:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Display Suite 6 row template.
 */
?>
<<?php print $layout_wrapper; print $layout_attributes; ?> class="ds-6row <?php print $classes;?> clearfix">

  <?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <<?php print $first_wrapper ?> class="group-first<?php print $first_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $first; ?>
  </<?php print $first_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $second_wrapper ?> class="group-second<?php print $second_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $second; ?>
  </<?php print $second_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $third_wrapper ?> class="group-third<?php print $third_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $third; ?>
  </<?php print $third_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $fourth_wrapper ?> class="group-fourth<?php print $fourth_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $fourth; ?>
  </<?php print $fourth_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $fifth_wrapper ?> class="group-fifth<?php print $fifth_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $fifth; ?>
  </<?php print $fifth_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $sixth_wrapper ?> class="group-sixth<?php print $sixth_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $sixth; ?>
  </<?php print $sixth_wrapper ?>>

</<?php print $layout_wrapper ?>>

<?php if (!empty($drupal_render_children)): ?>
  <?php print $drupal_render_children ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the [code for Display Suite](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/includes/ds.registry.inc), specifically the block mentioned in the error message:

```
function _ds_layouts_scan_theme($theme, &$layouts) {
  $theme_layouts = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('theme', $theme) . '/ds_layouts', '/inc$/');
  foreach ($theme_layouts as $file => $values) {
    include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file);
    $function = 'ds_' . $values->name;
    $layouts[$values->name] = $function();
    $layouts[$values->name]['path'] = str_replace('/' . $values->filename, '', $file);
  }
}
```

Note that when it goes looking for layouts is it prepending your layout name with 'ds_'.

I imagine this is to prevent functions being included that were not intended for this purpose, a bit like using your module name in place of `hook_` when you implement hooks.

That's why changing your function name worked.

Comment: Exactly, +1. It takes the file name and preprends ds_ onto it to get the function name to call. And even the documentation referred to makes this naming pattern clear enough.

Comment: It is clear enough in the documentation if you know what to look for, I was flummoxed by this kind of thing only a few months ago so I'm happy to point out the solution on occasion =)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by editing ds_6row.inc. I changed

`<?php
function ds_6row() {`

to

```
<?php
function ds_ds_6row() {
```

If anyone can tell me why this worked. I'll be a happy man.